# Can't get profile from user object

Tags: django, profile

I'm trying to get the profile of users with the `get_profile()` method. My `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` is well set I guess but I'm getting this error message:

> Unable to load the profile model, check AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in your project settings

Do you think it's because I've linked the profile model to the user with a `foreignKey` field instead of a `OneToOne` field?

I'm asking before proceeding to changes because I don't want to break my app.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the ForeignKey. Did you add the profile app in your settings.py?

Comment: Yes. When I pass the profile to the template everything work.

Comment: I thought you were getting errors when trying to get the profile. So if you're able to pass the profile to the template, I guess you're able to grab the profile. When does your error occur, then?

Comment: I can pass a profile object to the template but I'd rather like to use the get_profile() method, e.g. something like {{ user.get_profile.avatar }}, and when I try I get the message I've put in my post.

Comment: Hm. Okay. Can you show the line with AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in your settings.py and then the model file containing the profile model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'app_containing_profile_model.name_of_profile_model'
```

Say you have a **profiles** app with models.py containing the profile model, defined by the class **Profile**. Then you'd have:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'profiles.Profile'
```

Is your project already configured as such?

Comment: No it wasn't ! I put 'name_of_project.app_containing_profile'. I misunderstood the doc. It's perfectly working now. Thanks for your answers !

Comment: @user1026355 If this answer solved your problem, you could select it as your accepted one.